# Dynamically add tabpanel to tabcontrol

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to dynamically add  tab panel to tabcontainer

I have written the code.

I has no errors, but still its not showing me tabs.

My code:

```
ds = gc.GetDataToListBinder("select distinct(tabname) from Parameteronline where isactive='Y'")



            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                Dim tpParameter As AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel = New AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel()

                tpParameter.ID = "Panel_" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()
                tpParameter.HeaderText = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString()

                Dim tc As AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer = New AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer()

                tc.Tabs.Add(tpParameter)

            Next
```

ds is dataset here. I am getting tab panel's header text from this dataset.

Code has no errors. But still its not showing me result (tabcontainer)

Please help me.

Comment: I see no place where you added it to the page. It will also be gone on postback.

Comment: then how should i place this tabcontainer on page? i thought it automatically gets added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a container for the control to be placed. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)